# How to fit responsive wrapper canvas signature_pad in the div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, canvas, signaturepad

I'm trying to manage my wrapper/canvas on responsive view to fit in the div. The problem is that it overflows the div's frame (look at screenshot)

I tried to play with min-width and max-width but nothing works correctly.

[My Fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/2w1Labxn/)

```
.wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    position: relative;
    width: 262px;
    height: 150px;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.signature_client,
.signature_tech {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 280px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you remove the padding it fixes the problem

```
.table>tbody>tr>td {
      padding:8px 0px;
  }
```

Comment: Well, i tried your css code but that doesn't solve the problem, look @ https://jsfiddle.net/2w1Labxn/1/

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @Peacefull make the wrapper{  width: 100%;} .signature_client, .signature_tech {width:100% } instead of  width: 262px;